# Combining multiple iterators over same range in Rust

Tags: string, rust, iterator

I am trying to understand how (and why) Rust iterators over the same span can not be combined (easily?).

Here's the code fragment causing the issues:

```rs
let fold_size = 1;
let field = "12345678\n12345678";

let fold1 = field.lines().take(fold_size);
let fold2 = field.lines().skip(fold_size).take(fold_size).rev();

let folds = fold1.zip(fold2);

if folds.all(|(a, b)| a == b) {
    return fold + 1
}
```

Essentially this code is trying to iterate over different lines of the same string few times and compare them. At least that was my intention.

When I try to compile this code, however, the compiler throws multiple errors which I can not understand:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::str::Lines<'_>: ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied

let fold2 = field.lines().skip(fold_size).take(fold_size).rev();
                                                          ^^^ the trait `ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for `std::str::Lines<'_>`
```

As far as I can tell, this is Rust telling me the iterator over lines does not meet some requirements (which I do not really understand - the `take(n)` looks like an "exact size iterator" to me).

This is weird, but I can work this around by using a suboptimal hack - materializing the iterator into a vector:

```rs
let fold2 = field.lines().skip(fold_size).take(fold_size).collect::<Vec<_>>().iter().rev();
```

The other error (if the above hack is not implemented) has to do with `zip` operation:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::str::Lines<'_>: ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied

let folds = fold1.zip(fold2); // the trait bound `std::str::Lines<'_>: std::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied
                  ^^^ the trait `ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for `std::str::Lines<'_>`
```

Which seems like the same issue as with the `rev` operation.

The next error occurs on the `all` operation:

```
error[E0599]: the method `all` exists for struct `Zip<Take<Lines<'_>>, Rev<Take<Skip<Lines<'_>>>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

if folds.all(|(a, b)| a == b) {
         ^^^ method cannot be called on `Zip<Take<Lines<'_>>, Rev<Take<Skip<Lines<'_>>>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

     |
15   | pub struct Rev<T> {
     | ----------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
     |
13   | pub struct Zip<A, B> {
     | -------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
     |
```

Which, again, does not make any sense to me.

The one super suspicious warning is being thrown on top of that by the `rust-analyzer`:

```
if folds.all(|(a, b)| a == b) {
   ^^^^^
cannot mutate immutable variable `folds`rust-analyzer (E0384)
---
let folds: Zip<Take<Lines<'_>>, <Rev<Take<Skip<Lines<'_>>>> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>
```

Which does not make any sense to me - does not seem like I am (explicitly) mutating the iterator. I can understand how the operation has to iterate over the range, but shouldn't that be a new iterator instance?

All of the aforementioned operations are supposed to return an iterator, according to the docs ([`Lines::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html#method.rev), [`Lines::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html#method.take), [`Lines::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html#method.zip))?

My understanding is that these iterators should be a "zero-cost abstraction", merely describing the way to iterate over a range of values in the same collection.

But apparently something is missing either in the iterators' implementation or in my code using these iterators - I just can't grasp what exactly is wrong here. Or I might be misunderstanding the core concept in the Rust iterators.

Comment: "but shouldn't that be a new iterator instance?" - No, Rust never copies anything non-trivial (and iterators are usually not trivial) without you explicitly telling it to.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements in a `Lines` depends on the input, so it can't implement `ExactSizeIterator` (at least not without looking at the complete string upon it's creation, but `Iterator`s are supposed to be lazy in Rust), further `take(n)` returns an iterator of **up to** `n` elements, if the contained iterator is shorter, so is the resulting `Take`, so it can only implement `ExactSizeIterator` if the contained iterator does.

The problem now is that `Take` only [implements `DoubleEndededIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Take.html#impl-DoubleEndedIterator-for-Take%3CI%3E) iff the contained iterator implements `DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator` because of how it is implemented.

You probably should just collect the lines into a temporary `Vec`.

Comment: nit: `Take` does implement `ExactSizeIterator` as long as the wrapped iterator does, it just returns `min(self.wrapped.len(), self.n)`.

Comment: I am not sure I see the reason for `Lines` to _not_ know the input at creation time. Especially since the string it is created from is immutable.

Comment: So tell me how many lines does the string `"…"` have, where `…` is an unknown number of characters that might contain newlines, you're not allowed to look at the actual characters, because that is work that a **lazy** iterator can only do when it's iterated upon, not when it's created. There is no reason you can't implement an alternative `Lines` that implements `ExactSizeIterator`, but it's creation is `O(n)` not `O(1)`.

Comment: that explains it, cheers! i just wonder if the string is already in memory, and the string is immutable, if we iterate over the lines once - should we not have them cached? at this stage I seem like trying to justify the use of iterators instead of just using `for` loop, hehe

Comment: That can only happen in an optimization, not at the type level like would be required here. The codes context (having called and iterated the iterator once) changing other code's behaviour seems very surprising and not a quality I look for in a programming language tbh.

Comment: well, true. i wish i could combine the two answers + all of these comments into one - that would answer all the bits of my question

Answer (score 1):

> Which does not make any sense to me - does not seem like I am (explicitly) mutating the iterator. I can understand how the operation has to iterate over the range, but shouldn't that be a new iterator instance?

If you look at its signature it says:

```
fn all<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> bool
```

so `all` does not take ownership of the subject iterator, it just modifies the iterator in place.

That's why it complains, it needs `folds` to be `mut`. I assume it's like that because it shortcuts (this is documented) so technically you could use the rest of the iterator after its "failure" (same with `any`), without needing to `by_ref` them first. Not sure that's a major use case but I assume that's why they take the subject by reference instead of value unlike for_each, fold, reduce, min/max, scan, ... (but like nth, and like try_fold / try_for_each since those can also stop during iteration).

Also would be nice if you posted errors and snippets which match, because the error I get for the folds issue is:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `folds` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:8
   |
10 |     if folds.all(|(a, b)| a == b) {
   |        ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
help: consider changing this to be mutable
   |
8  |     let mut folds = fold1.zip(fold2);
   |         +++
```

which could hardly be clearer.

> My understanding is that these iterators should be a "zero-cost abstraction", merely describing the way to iterate over a range of values in the same collection.

It's *because* they are zero-cost that they have those limitations: for an iterator to be reversible with no overhead it needs to be iterable both ways, otherwise to reverse it you have to iterate it forwards collecting it into a buffer, then iterate that buffer backwards.

And for `take` to be iterable backwards, it needs not only its underlying iterator to be iterable backwards, but it needs to skip ahead (well back) to reach its own records, so it needs to know how many records of the underlying iterator it has to skip. Therefore it needs to know exactly how many records the underlying iterator will produce. `skip` has similar issues, from the front it can just skip records until it reaches its quota, but from the back it now needs to know how many records it can yield, which it needs the ability to compute ahead of time.

The alternative would require keeping some sort of read-ahead window, which would require allocating a buffer, which would not be zero-cost.

Comment: The reason I did not post snippets is because I am trying to understand why the error is happening rather than just fix it.